# Google maps api fails to load map tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google maps api v3 embedded into my website and it all worked fine up until a couple of weeks back. Within the last weeks, every now and then the map tiles (only the map, satellite tiles work fine all the time) fail to load for a couple of hours, sometimes days. Along with that i get the following two 403 error messages:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 
(Forbidden) (ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo, line 0)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 
(Forbidden) (AuthenticationService.Authenticate, line 0)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate
```

It seems like something with the authentication goes wrong. However, i am nowhere near the maximum number of calls to the api per day. Moreover, the map controls as well as the satellite tiles (when i switch over to them) load without problems.

The issue occurs randomly a few times a week for a couple of ours, up to an entire day. Most of the time everything works fine.

Has anybody experienced such issues before or any idea on what could be going wrong?

**Update feb 2016: still dealing with the same problem**

Upon closer examination, it appears that every time after updating the website the map tiles work for a couple of days, before the 403 messages appear again.

Usage statistics in the google developper console show that I barely ever exceed 100 requests per day, so usage limits should not be a problem at all.

By now I did request a new API key to see if that would help. After I changed the key, like after a site update for a couple of days everything was working fine, however by now we are back at the same old situation

Comment: How are you loading the API?

Comment: I'm loading the javascript directly from google's servers: <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

Comment: If you don't use a key, the quota is per-domain. Are you on a shared domain? It's possible that somebody else is using your quota.

Comment: I use my own key, just didn't want to print it publicly here ;). I also checked the usage statistics with google. The maximum number of api calls per day that i reached were about 150, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: I don't think that it's authentication-issue, usually you would see an alert when authetication fails.  Try to clear the browser-cache.

Comment: I will try as soon as the issue comes up again. Right now everyting is working fine. What i can say is that it occurs independently of browser (tested on Safari, Chrome, Firefox) and it seems to be simultaneous on all client computers.

Comment: Tried emptying and disabling caches, to no succes. The map is still not loading, while the satellite tiles work properly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, still no idea what causes this bug. For now i am using the satellite map as that works without problems.

Comment: Having the same issue this side.  I'm using the leaflet-google plugin in an Ionic mobile app though.  Satellite works.  Street doesn't work.  Hybrid works but without the streets.  Stopped on all places whether I go through the Wi-Fi or 3G, yet going to maps.google.com those tiles loads fine.  I suspect it has to do with the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally this seems to be solved. It turns out that the problem was that I handled the included google maps javascript file with symfony's assetic. This caused the file to be cached on my webserver, and served to my users from there, which in turn triggered google's security measures to prevent tile scraping, causing the 403 responses.

The solution was very simpel, to use simple `<script src=".."></script>` tags instead of assetic's and twig's `{% javascripts '..' %}` tag.

Why this only caused problems with the map, and not with the satellite images, i have no idea!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the same issue on GMaps API on WordPress site.

Issue was caused by aggressive caching.

Purging W3 Total Cache solved the issue for now. Setting less aggressive caching policy should prevent the issue from happening again.